# How to replace text values in cfg files loaded in blueprint/context.xml

Tags: java, osgi, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

I'm loading a cfg file in my context.xml under OSGi-inf/blueprint/ 
in my context.xml file:

...

```
<cm:property-placeholder
        persistent-id="com.lolo.${project.version}"
        update-strategy="reload">
        <cm:default-properties>
            <cm:property name="testValue" value="" />
        </cm:default-properties>
    </cm:property-placeholder>
<ext:property-placeholder placeholder-prefix="$sys["
        placeholder-suffix="]" />
```

in my cfg file I got:

```
testValue=$sys[jdbcUrl]
```

this loads correctly  the jdbc env property and injects it in the context.xml ( the testValue will be later injected in a Java class, which is is very useful)

my problem is whenever I remove this code

```
`<ext:property-placeholder placeholder-prefix="$sys["
        placeholder-suffix="]" />`
```

and i replace

`testValue=$sys[jdbcUrl]`

```
with
```

`testValue=${project.version}`

now I don't get the same behaviour as before, the project.version is not loaded the testValue stays empty
 what should I do to correctly inject `${projetc.version}` ?

Answer (score 0):

The ext:property-placeholder definition means that you can refer to any system property using $sys[].

So to access the property project.version try: $sys[project.version].
Of course to make this work you must provide the system property for example in the surefire config.